# How can I create more than one 2D Magic Square array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I've been working on some code that would generate a magic square which is basically a 2d array of size n x n with elements ranging from 1 to n^2 with each column, row, and diagonal summing up to a same number.

here is what I have so far, the problem is that it creates the same 2d array each time. I start by placing 1 in the rightmost middle row. Would this same approach allow me to create 3 more magic squares?

```
std::cout << "Enter the size of a magic square: \n";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    int magicSquare[n][n];

    // set all slots as 0
    memset(magicSquare, 0, sizeof(magicSquare));

    // Initialize position for 1
    int row = n/2;
    int col = n-1;


    for (int num=1; num <= n*n; )
    {
        if (row==-1 && col==n)
        {
            row = 0;
            col = n-2;
        }
        else
        {

            if (col == n)
                col = 0;

            if (row < 0)
                row=n-1;
        }
        if (magicSquare[row][col])
        {
            col -= 2;
            row++;
            continue;
        }
        else
            magicSquare[row][col] = num++;

        col++;
        row--;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Magic squares exhibit [reflection symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_symmetry).

You can exploit this property to make additional magic squares, as an **example**:

Here is the **base** 3x3 magic square generated with your program:

```
2 9 4 
7 5 3 
6 1 8
```

+1: The same square **mirrored horizontally**:

```
4 9 2 
3 5 7 
8 1 6
```

+2: The original square **mirrored vertically**:

```
6 1 8 
7 5 3 
2 9 4
```

+3: The original square **mirrored horizontally and vertically**:

```
8 1 6 
3 5 7 
4 9 2
```

All satisfy the properties of magic squares.

Comment: You can also mirror it along the diagonal axes, and you get two more magic squares.